# Exclude node package from build step

Tags: javascript, import, vite, rollup

I have my web app running on an edge environment where many of the node libraries are not supported. 
I am using the **PlanetScale** connector which does support edge, but lately I needed to start storing database snapshots for safety reasons (disclaimer: no databases were harmed prior to this decision.....) + it's easier for quick CI.

To connect to my local db snapshot, I would normally use mysql2. But the problem is that the mysql2 package is not edge compatible and therefore it fails the build step.

Logically as I wouldn't want the edge environment have access to the mysql connector, I tried to inline `import` the connector like this:

```js
...
let { CONNECTOR } = await import.meta.env
if (CONNECTOR === "mysql") {
   const mysql = await import("mysql2/promise");
}
...
```

Unfortunately this also did not work and failed the build step.

My last but **very very very wrong** approach was this **abomination**:

```js
...
let { CONNECTOR } = await import.meta.env
if (CONNECTOR === "mysql") {
   const mysql = await eval(`import("mysql2/promise")`);
}
...
```

Though I haven't ever been so much ashamed about my code, this surprisingly works. It does pass the build step and also works fine when using it in my dev environment.

I have tinkered a little bit with the rollup and vite config to no avail.
Is there any way I can achieve the same goal without this `eval` mess?

Note, that moving it as a dev dependency won't help either because Cloudflare does not pass the `--production` flag and it would probably throw an error at build time anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `rollup` directly or inside `vite` you should be able to check for `process.env.NODE_ENV` to make certain code work only in dev environment:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const mysql = await import("mysql2/promise");
}
```

this block should be removed in production builds and no `import` should be there.

Comment: I use Astro which uses Vite. Though this works on my local build, it fails in production. I know that I should remove this line when deploying but I wouldn't want the hustle of commenting out this portion of the code, whenever I would need to deploy. That's why used that nasty eval. Also, does rollup specifically checks for the `NODE_ENV` variable to conditionally transpile/whatever magic it does? Because it certainly did not do the trick with the CONNECTOR

Comment: Yes, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is a special expression. It is replaced by a static value (usually `"production"` or `"development"`) at build-time by most modern bundlers. After that it becomes `if ("production" === "development") { ... }` in release builds, which is optimised to an empty block.